# Any suggestions to keep track of software subscriptions?

Tags: software, expense-tracking, tracking

Any good methods to keep track of monthly/yearly subscriptions for software? Currently we have over 15 subscriptions and some of them are also depended by the number of users invited to that software.

Been using Google Sheets to track all of the expenses, it's a bit challenging to keep it up to date.

Comment: Who is "we"? Are you talking about your family? Or about a whole company? Keep in mind that this community only handles questions about *personal* finances. If it's on company-scale, then this might not be the best platform for your question.

Comment: It's a startup, thanks for pointing that out. Do you have any recommendations which platforms I could use for about business finances?

Comment: Questions about accounting for companies larger than one person [are off-topic here](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Unfortunately I don't think there is a sub-community on Stack Exchange which deals with questions about company finances at the moment.

Comment: A spreadsheet + calendar alerts is probably the best you'll get (unless you want to write a custom database application).

Comment: Thanks, both for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, keeping the record up to date is going to be the bit that you can’t automate unless you have either a deterministic way to calculate future subscription parameters (cost, number of seats, expiry, special discounts, etc) or a link between the app and each provider.

Since that is the sticking point, I don’t think any app on the market will help.

You can, however, employ someone to do this or assign the job to an appropriate member of your existing team. You’ll need to decide whether it’s worth the cost and HR overheads.

If the issue is simply getting reminders in a timely fashion, you can put the reminders into your diary.